# grouping time series data by threshold

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, dplyr

I have data that has a desired range but goes into areas that are considered too high or too low. I would like to be able to group instances of the points being too high or too low as separate instances. 
I made some fake data here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123432)
dat <- data.frame(value = sample(20:600, 20, replace=F))%>%
        mutate(ord = row_number(),
               cat = ifelse(value > 350, "high", 
                     ifelse(value < 90, "low", "good")),
               extreme = ifelse(cat=="high" & value > lag(value) & value > lead(value), "Peak",
                        ifelse(cat=="low" & value < lag(value) & value < lead(value), "Trough", "")))
```

And a graph of it here:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = ord, y = value))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 300, color="blue")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 120, color="blue")+
  coord_fixed(.025)
```

[image]

I know how to group these high & low areas in excel, but can't seem to replicate it in R. I would like to produce something like this (though E1 would be "Series"):

[image]

Notice column E is based on column C & there can be more than one peak/trough per series.

I hope this was clear and you folks can help. If possible, I would like to stick with dplyr.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you actually want. A plot? A separate data frame? Separate data frame columns? Define "separate instance" for us.

Comment: I want a column added to my data frame that looks like column E in the excel example. It should increase in value each time there is a change in the "cat" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description in the comments I think this is what you are looking for. Note that I parameterized the length with the variable `n`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123432)
n <- 20
dat <- data.frame(value = sample(20:600, n, replace=F))%>%
  mutate(ord = row_number(),
         cat = ifelse(value > 350, "high", 
                      ifelse(value < 90, "low", "good")),
         extreme = ifelse(cat=="high" & value > lag(value) & 
                                              value > lead(value), "Peak",
                          ifelse(cat=="low" & value < lag(value) & 
                                              value < lead(value), "Trough", "")),
         c1 = cat,
         c2 = c(cat[1],cat[1:(n-1)]),
         chg = cumsum(c2!=c1)+1      )
```

yielding:

```
   value ord  cat extreme   c1   c2 chg
1     96   1 good         good good   1
2    254   2 good         good good   1
3    458   3 high    Peak high good   2
4    453   4 high         high high   2
5    567   5 high    Peak high high   2
6    313   6 good         good high   3
7    353   7 high    Peak high good   4
8     20   8  low  Trough  low high   5
9    487   9 high    Peak high  low   6
10    48  10  low  Trough  low high   7
11   288  11 good         good  low   8
12   171  12 good         good good   8
13   175  13 good         good good   8
14   462  14 high    Peak high good   9
15    95  15 good         good high  10
16   360  16 high         high good  11
17   407  17 high         high high  11
18   484  18 high    Peak high high  11
19   159  19 good         good high  12
20    36  20  low    <NA>  low good  13
```

Comment: That's it! I'll have to explore more about how cumsum(...) works. Can this step be worked into a dplyr statement?

Comment: `mutate(dat, chg = cumsum(cat != lag(as.character(cat), default = cat[1]))`  

Thanks for your help. Your code got me to the above one liner. Because the first lag value is an `NA`, I use the `default` argument to fill in the NA value with the first row of `dat$cat`

Comment: Nice one. I try to stick to base as much a possible, never understood why base does not have a `lag` or a `rotate`.